# vs code localhost refused to connect react

Tags: reactjs, localhost

I'm creating a keeper app on react, i'm using vs code for writing code. Honestly I'm very new to programming and stuff so big words would go wooosh!

the thing is when i press F5 in vs code it's supposed to debug the code, open a localhost in browser window and display outputs. but when i press F5, it does open a new browser window, but it says this
[localhost refused to connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaeAJ.png)

Now i have tried lots of things,

1. cd into the folder npm start then localhost:3000
2. checked my system's firewall settings
3. changed paths in .json file
4. installed some extensions
5. restarted system
6. tried running on different system.

nothing worked!

there's a similar stackoverflow question, i've gone through that too.

please help, otherwise i've to keep learning react on codesandbox.
any help would be appreciated, thanks!

code for my .json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*" }

    }
]
```

}

Comment: Just to confirm, you said you run it on localhost:3000 but the URL in your screenshot is localhost:8080. I see the "url" property in your configuration is localhost:8080, but I don't see that in the docs. I do however see a "port", so maybe you want to change the URL line to `"port": 8080`? Or try just opening localhost:3000 instead if that's the default.

Comment: @James hey, thankyou for answering! i tried running it on 3000 yes but i did this after i went for alternative solutions. I tried however, changing 8080 to 3000 but it showed the same localhost refused to connect, i changed the port as well, like you said, it just opened the homepage of my browser window